# Titan + DynamoDB slow upload of Edges

Tags: performance, amazon-dynamodb, database-performance, titan

I am developing a recommendation system based on Titan (1.0.0) + DynamoDB backend.
Currently I try to migrate all our user base (millions) and their relationships (billions).
When I make a user base migration (just creation of Vertex with one indexed property) I can see direct relationship between

`storage.dynamodb.stores.edgestore.capacity-write`

`storage.dynamodb.stores.edgestore.write-rate`

and uploading speed. If I need increase speed -> I just set more read/write capacity on the `edgestore` table and increase value of these properties in TitanGraph.

But it does not work for relationships. As I can see from CloudWatch monitoring `edgestore` table have enough free capacity but my uploading process can not utilize them all. I can not increase the uploading speed more then 6000 write capacity units and it’s too slow.

Do somebody know what the problem?

Here is my [TitanGraph](https://gist.github.com/angryTit/ab6951240f66fa4cc6d5312edb7ac8b0)

Comment: You linked me to your configuration. Can you link to your loading code? You may be experiencing a bottleneck elsewhere. What kind of host are you running your loader on? Properties of the network connection (latency on your DynamoDB UpdateItem calls, available bandwidth, etc)?

Comment: You seem to be running against DynamoDB in ap-southeast-1. The max throughput per table there is 10k reads and 10k writes per second: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-capacity-units-provisioned-throughput

Comment: Hi Alexander, here is the loading code https://gist.github.com/angryTit/c9462c58a13619f700f18f1707b1ae53 I running it on m4.16xlarge instance in the same region. And during relationships uploading it takes only 6000 write capacity from 10000 on the table.

Comment: mb bottleneck is here https://gist.github.com/angryTit/c9462c58a13619f700f18f1707b1ae53#file-gistfile1-txt-L87 but it's indexed property.. and strange that Titan does not use all read capacity on the table in this moment